# Performance of variable-length types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Is there a significant (say, >10%) penalty in reading speed of variable-length types (varchar, varbinary) as opposed to fixed-length types?

Scenario: instead of using varchar, I can use char(30) which will be enough in all cases.

I'm using C# to access the db. (Perhaps that matters.)

Comment: Can't say for sure. But logically, varchar can't be saved in-place - it should point to some location in DB file. So reading it should have overhead of searching the reference. If char(30) is definitely enough, I wouldn't use nvarchar anyway (the space economy would me minimal). But it's only an assumption and I can't measure the overhead in percent

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy actually, that is not true; `varchar(somenumber)` is in-row data. Even `varchar(max)` *can* be in-row, via "text in row" - you can configure how much data to hold in-row before switching to out-of-row. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: To answer that you would need to test it on your *actual* setup. Frankly I expect the answer to be "no". Since you are talking about access from C#, network bandwidth is perhaps the most significant aspect - I haven't dug deeply into TDS, but my *understanding* is that a `char(30)` will always use 30 bytes TDS payload (plus headers etc); if that assumption is correct, then `varchar(30)` could be significantly *cheaper* if the data is usually less than 30 characters.

Comment: for the db it matters, a char(4) always needs 4bytes.
a varchar(4) can be 1, 3 or 5 Bytes depending of how many chars are inside.